# CSS Selector unordered list image name

Tags: css, image, html, alt

From the html shown below I want to select all the odd numbered, li class="items-3", then select the three descriptions of the pictures, shown highlighted below using either,
 using,** span data-picture="" data-alt=**"Red Range Rover Evoque">**, or using the img tag img alt=**"Red Range Rover Evoque"** src="/Images/Evoque-Red-Street.

I have tried the following css:

**li.items-3:first-child  div:first-child a span[data-alt]:first-child**

which gives me :

**span data-picture="" data-alt="Red Range Rover Evoque" class=""**

But I can't seem get the data-alt value, I have tried the css below but that doesn'twor either,

**li.items-3:first-child  div:first-child a span[data-alt]:first-child > span[data-alt>**

I would be grateful if someone could suggest a solution.

Thanks

```
 <ul class="mediaCarousel" style="text-align: left; float: none; position:   absolute; top: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 11693px; height: 842px;">
     <li class="items-3" style="width: 1063px;">
     <div class="el">
       <a href="/Images/Evoque-Red-Street-1200x600_tcm186-51405.jpg">
          <span data-picture="" data-alt=**"Red Range Rover Evoque">**
          <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Red-Street-1200x600_tcm186-51405.jpg"></span>
          <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Red-Street-1200x600_tcm186-51405.jpg" data-media="(max-width: 400px)"></span>
          <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Red-Street-1200x600_tcm186-51405.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)">
               <img alt="Red Range Rover Evoque" src="/Images/Evoque-Red-Street-1200x600_tcm186-51405.jpg">
          </span>
          <noscript> 
                <img alt="Red Range Rover Evoque" src="/Images/Evoque-Red-Street-1200x600_tcm186-51405.jpg" /> 
          </noscript>
          </span>
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="el width-1of2">
  <a href="/Images/Evoque-Outdoor-Cinema-600x350_tcm186-51407.jpg">
    <span data-picture="" data-alt="**Red Range Rover Evoque at an outdoor cinema**">
    <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Outdoor-Cinema-600x350_tcm186-51407.jpg"></span>
    <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Outdoor-Cinema-600x350_tcm186-51407.jpg" data-media="(max-width: 400px)"></span>
    <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Outdoor-Cinema-600x350_tcm186-51407.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)">
         <img alt="Red Range Rover Evoque at an outdoor cinema" src="/Images/Evoque-Outdoor-Cinema-600x350_tcm186-51407.jpg">
  </span>
  <noscript> 
        <img alt="Red Range Rover Evoque at an outdoor cinema" src="/Images/Evoque-Outdoor-Cinema-600x350_tcm186-51407.jpg" /> 
  </noscript>
  </span>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="el width-1of2">
    <a href="/Images/Evoque-Front-View-Red-600x350_tcm186-51406.jpg">
    <span data-picture="" data-alt="**Red Range Rover Evoque Front View**">
    <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Front-View-Red-600x350_tcm186-51406.jpg"></span>
    <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Front-View-Red-600x350_tcm186-51406.jpg" data-media="(max-width: 400px)"></span>
    <span data-src="/Images/Evoque-Front-View-Red-600x350_tcm186-51406.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)">
    <noscript> 
         <img alt="Red Range Rover Evoque Front View" src="/Images/Evoque-Front-View-Red-600x350_tcm186-51406.jpg" />
   </noscript>
   </span>
   </a>
   </div>
   </li>
   <li class="items-1" style="width: 1063px;">
   <li class="items-3" style="width: 1063px;">
   <li class="items-1" style="width: 1063px;">
   <li class="items-3" style="width: 1063px;">
 </ul>
```

Comment: I think you might be getting CSS confused with JS. This can easily be done using Javscript or jQuery, and impossible to do in CSS (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: @RCorrie is right. I was baffled by the idea how could you do this with css

Comment: WebElement span_element = im1.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.items-3:first-child  div:first-child a span[data-alt]:first-child"));
            
            String alt =  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes['alt'].value;",span_element.toString());
     System.out.println(span_element.getText());

Answer (score 0):

Try with this selector:

```
li.items-3 span[data-alt*="Red Range Rover"]  span
```

It's hard to make a demo with your code but here you have it http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Xr6/5/

Comment: The problem is the description is not going to be "Red Range Rover" always, its going to vary as we move along the list of images, i.e it could be "Red Range Rover Evoque" or "Red Range Rover Evoque Front View" etc as loop around the list items items-3.

Comment: That's why in the data-alt the selector has an `*` to match all datas that include those words in any part...so you can use just a few words that match in all datas like red range rover try changing in html and you see the selector keeps working

Comment: sorry, I meant it could be something like 'Freelander 2` in the other <li class="items-3" style="width: 1063px;"> items. i.e    <img class="carousel-image" width="930" height="530" title="Adventure awaits" alt="Freelander 2 driving on non-paved coastal road" src="/static/images/content/L359_14_EXT_LOC09_01.1.jpg">